# tkinter: button color does not update

Tags: python, button, tkinter, colors, updates

The button3 of my GUI is calling a function which takes quite long to calculate stuff. So in the meantime I want to change the buttons text and color:

```
self.button3.config(foreground='red')
self.button3['text'] = 'PLEASE WAIT ...'
self.button3.update_idletasks()
```

The text of the button does indeed change, but the color stays the same. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button probably remains in its **active state** during the long calculation. So you may want to set its `activeforeground` color to red:

```
self.button3.config(activeforeground='red')
```

> activeforeground = What foreground color to use when the button is
>   active. The default is system specific. (activeForeground/Background)

[(Tkinter Button documentation)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Comment: ahh thank you, that works as intended. however I cannot set activeforeground in my \_\_init\_\_ (the button is part of a class) because that will result in the button text turning red upon hovering over it. so clicking the button sets it to active AND hovering over it. I'm assuming that the button returns to non-active state as soon as the main loop is back? I'm still searching for a good tutorial that clarifies all of this behaviour. thank you very much for the solution :)